# Show that a simple group of order 60 has no proper subgroup of order greater than 12

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to show that any simple group of order $60$ has no proper subgroup of order greater than $12$.

I know that $G$ is isomorphic to $A_5$, a non-abelian simple group of order $60$. I suppose there exists a group $H$ such that $H < A_5$ and $|H|>12$. My idea is to look for a contradiction, but I'm not sure what to do next. 
Could you give me a hint for how to proceed please? Thanks!

Comment: If a group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $n$, then this implies that there is a non-trivial homomorphism $f:G\to S_n$. This is because $G$ acts transitively on the set $G/H$ of $n$ elements. What do you know about kernels of homomorphisms? In particular when $G$ is simple?

Comment: Thanks :) So just to check I understood: I take a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of order $\frac{|G|}{n}$ . Then $f:G \to S_n$ is a non-trivial homomorphism. Since $G$ is simple, it has precisely two normal subgroups: $\{e\}$ and $G$. The kernel is normal, hence it is equal to one of these, but we want the homomorphism to be non-trivial, so we exclude $G$ and are left with $\ker f = \{e\}$. But how does this show the question I posted?

Comment: If $n<5$, then $|S_n|<60$ and $f$ cannot be injective contradicting what you observed. Therefore $n\ge5$, so $|H|=\frac{|G|}n\le12.$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

In a general group $\;G\;$ with a subgroup $\;H\;,\;\;\;[G:H]=n\;$ . Putting $\;X:=H/G:=$ the set of all left cosets of $\;H\;$ in $\;G\;$ , define an action (the regular action) $\;G\times X\to X\;$ by

$$x\cdot(gH):=(xg)H\;,\;\;\forall\,x,g\in G$$

== Show the above *indeed* is a group action

== Show that group action determines a group homomorphism $\;\phi:G\to Sym(X)\cong S_n\;$

== Show that $\;H\le \ker\phi\;$ and , in fact, $\;\ker\phi\;$ is the maximal normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ which contains $\;H\;$ .

From the above we get that $\;G\cong T\le S_n\iff \phi\;$ is injective iff there are no non-trivial normal subgroups of $\;G\;$ contained in $\;H\;$

Bonus (for you): prove that in fact

$$\ker\phi=\bigcap_{g\in G}H^g=:\text{the core of}\;\;H$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain what $T$ is and what the core of $H$ is?

Comment: @user197311 Apply the first isomorphism theorem: $$G/\ker\phi\cong\phi(G)\le S_n\;,\;\;\text{so in fact}\;\;T=\phi(G)$$ About the core: it is what is written there: the intersection of *all* the conjugates of $\;H\;$

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how we arrive at the conclusion please? How do we know that if $G$ is simple of order 60, we can't have (for example) a proper subgroup of order $15$?

Comment: Suppose $\;H\le G\;,\;\;|H|=15\implies [G:H]=4\;$ . From what is written above, and since there are no non-trivial normal subgroups of $\;G\;$ , we get that $\;\ker\phi=1\iff G/\ker\phi\cong G\;$ . But then we get that $\;G\;$ is ismorphic to a subgroup of $\;S_4\;$, which cannot be as $\;|G|=60\;,\;\;|S_4|=24\;$ !